# Components required for building Virtual Lab using VMWare ESXI

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware

I am looking for hardware specifications required for setting up a virtual lab. I am planning to host 40-60 machines up & would to run them 24x7. I'm currently looking at purchasing my first server with the intent of building a home pentesting Lab that will eventually branch out to allow multiple users access the lab. The server will also host a Capture The Flag (CTF) style competition.The is being done for both my own learning and because I'm part of an infosec society, I want other members members to be able to learn in a safe and secure environment. The maximum number of users I would say is probably 60max and most of the VM's are Windows & Linux based.

Components Suggestions Required :

**Component**                            **Specification Required and Name of Config**

- Processor
- Motherboard
- Cooler
- RAM
- Graphic Card
- Power Supply
- SSD Primary
- HDD Secondary
- Case

Apart from that i would be also creating video content using camtasia studio where the length of video will be 20-30 min long. Please suggest the Complete Hardware specification required for the current requirement.

Comment: Questions seeking hardware recommendations are out of scope here at Super User

Answer (score 0):

Compute (CPU, RAM, GPU) resources depends on workload generated from all 60 VMs. Only the amount of VMs doesn’t give any numbers to recommend hardware.

CPU: For low/moderate workload you may have 1 physical CPU core for 4 VMs, so 16 cores are required least. More about vCPU-to-pCPU - https://download3.vmware.com/vcat/vmw-vcloud-architecture-toolkit-spv1-webworks/index.html

MoBo: based on CPU choice

RAM: calculate assigned RAM for each VM and add 20%. I’d say 128GB would be a minimum for 60VMs

GPU: very specific usage in virtualized infrastructure. It is required if you are going to run GPU-intensive applications in VMs (Autodesk, Photoshop, etc) , mining or bruteforcing passwords. Camtasia studio doesn;t require GPU. Virtualizing CPU may also require additional license, like NVIDIA Grid. Most infrastructures don’t require any GPU.

Storage: use local RAID. Any enterprise level SSD will suit well -
http://www.vmwareblog.org/shopping-ssds-several-tips-help-make-right-choice/

Avoid SMR HDD, because of poor write perfromance https://www.crn.com/news/storage/300079645/the-biggest-change-to-hdd-tech-youve-never-heard-of-yet.htm